# Find the solution of $u_t + bu_x = 0$

Tags: partial-differential-equations, linear-pde

let  $b  \in \mathbb{R} $be  constant  .Solve:

$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial t} (x,t) + b \frac{ \partial  u}{\partial x}(x,t) =0 , \quad x \in  \mathbb{R}, \quad t >0$$

$$ u(x,0) = x^2$$

My attempt : $\frac{\partial}{\partial t} u (x,t) =- b \frac{ \partial  u}{\partial x}(x,t) $ , Now  again differenting  both l.h.S and r.h.s , we get $$\frac{\partial^2}{\partial t^2} (x,t) =- b \frac{ \partial^2  u}{\partial x^2}(x,t) $$

after that applying the  D alembert formula  we have $$u(x,t) = \frac{(x+ bt)^2 +(x-bt)^2}{2} + \frac{1}{2b}\int_{x-bt}^{x+bt}0\,{\rm d}s.$$

Is its  true  ?

Comment: This is not true since you would have to differentiate both sides with respect to the same variable.

Comment: Use the [method of characteristics.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_characteristics#Example)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\frac{\partial u}{ dt} (x,t) + b \frac{ \partial  u}{dx}(x,t) =0 $$
With the method of characteristics the general solution is immediate :
$$u(x,t)=F(x-bt)$$
with arbitrary function $F$.

Condition : $u(x,0)=F(x)=x^2$. Now the function is known : $F(X)=X^2$ . We put it into the above general solution where  $X=(x-bt)$ .
$$u(x,t)=(x-bt)^2$$

Answer (score 2):

Your approach is correct provided that the solution is sufficiently smooth (which is the case here). However, you made some mistakes in the derivation of the solution.
Indeed, differentiating the linear advection equation $u_t + b u_x = 0$ w.r.t. $t$, we have
$u_{tt} = -b u_{xt}$.
Now, we use the equality of mixed derivatives $u_{xt} = u_{tx}$, and the initial PDE itself $u_{tx} = -b u_{xx}$ after differentiation w.r.t. $x$. Thus, the wave equation
$$
u_{tt} = b^2 u_{xx}
$$
is obtained.
[D'Alembert's solution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/D%27Alembert%27s_formula) for the initial condition $u(x,0) = x^2$ and $$u_t(x,0) = -b u_x(x, 0 ) = -2b x$$ reads
\begin{aligned}
u(x,t) &= \tfrac{1}{2} \left[(x+b t)^2 + (x-b t)^2\right] - \int_{x-bt}^{x+bt} \xi \,\text d \xi \\
&= (x-bt)^2 .
\end{aligned}
This is exactly the solution obtained by the more straightforward [method of characteristics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_characteristics) (see answer by @JJacquelin).

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

Let $$\hat u(\alpha ,t)=\int_{\mathbb R}u(x,t)e^{-2i\pi \alpha x}\,\mathrm d x.$$
Then, $$\partial _xu(x,t)+b\partial _tu(x,t)=0\iff \frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm d t}\hat u(\alpha ,t)-2i\pi \alpha \cdot \hat u(\alpha ,t)=0,$$
which is just a linear ODE to solve.

Answer (score 1):

Making the change of variables

$$
\cases{
\xi=x\\
\eta=x-b t
}
$$

we have

$$
u(x,t) = w(\xi,\eta)
$$

and after the change of variables we have

$$
b w_{\xi}(\xi,\eta)=0 \Rightarrow w(\xi,\eta) = \phi(\eta)
$$

now considering the initial conditions

$$
\phi(b x) = x^2\Rightarrow \phi(\eta) = \left(\frac{\eta}{b}\right)^2
$$

and finally

$$
u(x,t) = \left(x - b t\right)^2
$$

Comment: This would mean $u(x,0)=(x/b)^2$. There is a $b$ in excess.

Comment: You are right. Thanks. I'd  began to solve considering $u_x+b u_t = 0$ and in the rush to correct the mistake, I left the $b$.